# How can I aggregate columns, then find out the biggest changes over time and display the most outstanding ones?

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I'm a beginner in SQL and want to track the biggest changes in sales of tickets over time in absolute manner (so positive and negative) for a set of states (with a number of venders who can sell in every state they want) where the tickets are sold.

So I have a `state_table` like this:

| state_key | state_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alabama |
| 2 | Connecticut |
| 3 | Maine |

I have a `ticket_sales` table like this:

| vender_key | state_key | sell_date | no_of_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 27 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 48 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 69 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 31 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 41 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 10 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-01-01 | 15 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-02-01 | 11 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-02-01 | 21 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-02-01 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-02-01 | 67 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-02-01 | 39 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-02-01 | 13 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-02-01 | 19 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 77 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-01 | 68 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-03-01 | 59 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-03-01 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-03-01 | 11 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-03-01 | 49 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-03-01 | 54 |

Of course, the tables are much longer in real.

Now I want to know which states have the largest absolute difference in total ticket sales within the whole time frame. I want to display

- the name of the state
- the maximum date
- the number of sales at the maximum date in the respective state
- the minimum date
- the number of sales at the minimum date in the respective state and
- the difference between the maximum sales and the minimum sales for the top 3 states;

sorted descending by the difference between max and min sales per state.

My goal is to see which are the states with large changes in ticket sales over time, regardless if there is a positive or a negative development of sales.

So therefore, I need to sum up the venders' sales per state for each date first, then to pick the highest number of sales for each state and the corresponding date for each state. Then I have to do the same for the lowest number of sales and the corresponding date for each state. And at last, I need to calculate the absolute difference between these two numbers.

For me, this is a bit too much aggregation to handle in SQL, unfortunately. I have tried some code with `SUM` and `GROUP BY` states, but I don't know how to tell SQL the aggregation and then calculation correctly by choosing highest numbers per state (so the combination of `MAX` respectively `MIN` and `GROUP BY`), I'm confused by that.

My expected result should be:

| state_name | date_max | sales_max | date_min | sales_min | difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maine | 2021-03-01 | 113 | 2021-02-01 | 39 | 74 |
| Connecticut | 2021-03-01 | 128 | 2021-02-01 | 73 | 55 |
| Alabama | 2021-03-01 | 87 | 2021-01-01 | 58 | 29 |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: My expected result in this case would be:

Maine             2021-03-01   113   2021-02-01   39   74
Connecticut  2021-03-01   128   2021-02-01   73   55
Alabama        2021-03-01     87   2021-01-01   58   29

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with two aggregations. First find dates with max/min sum of `no_of_sales` for every `state_key` next aggregate it by `state_key` conditionally.

```
select state_key 
  , max(case nmin when 1 then sell_date end) date_min
  , max(case nmin when 1 then n end) sales_min
  , max(case nmax when 1 then sell_date end) date_max
  , max(case nmax when 1 then n end) sales_max
  , max(case nmax when 1 then n end) - max(case nmin when 1 then n end ) delta
from ( 
    select state_key, sell_date, sum(no_of_sales) n
       , row_number() over(partition by state_key order by sum(no_of_sales)) nmin
       , row_number() over(partition by state_key order by sum(no_of_sales) desc) nmax
    from ticket_sales
    group by state_key, sell_date
) t
where nmin = 1 or nmax = 1
group by state_key
ORDER BY delta DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Decoding the state name should be the last step.

```
select st.state_name, ts.date_min, ts.sales_min, ts.date_max, ts.sales_max,  ts.delta
from (
    select state_key 
      , max(case nmin when 1 then sell_date end) date_min
      , max(case nmin when 1 then n end) sales_min
      , max(case nmax when 1 then sell_date end) date_max
      , max(case nmax when 1 then n end) sales_max
      , max(case nmax when 1 then n end) - max(case nmin when 1 then n end ) delta
    from ( 
        select state_key, sell_date, sum(no_of_sales) n
           , row_number() over(partition by state_key order by sum(no_of_sales)) nmin
           , row_number() over(partition by state_key order by sum(no_of_sales) desc) nmax
        from ticket_sales
        group by state_key, sell_date
    ) t
    where nmin = 1 or nmax = 1
    group by state_key
    ORDER BY delta DESC 
    FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY 
) ts
join state_table st on ts.state_key = st.state_key
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I would never have managed that alone!

I added

order by delta desc
fetch first 10 rows only

to receive only the 10 states with the largest differences.

One more question:

Where in the code can I add a JOIN or something like that to merge with the table 'state_table' in order to display the 'state_name' as well?

Thank you!

Comment: You can join the query in the answer ,   `select .. from (<the above query>) t join  state_table ..`, @Christof

Comment: Thank you. I have added "ts" as an alias for the table "ticket_sales" and tried to insert code so that it looks like

`JOIN state_table st`
`ON st.state_key = ts.state_key`
`WHERE nmin = 1 or nmax = 1`
`GROUP BY state_key`
`ORDER BY delta DESC`
`FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY`

 after `(<query>) t` , but I always get error messages like


`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "ts"`
`LINE 15: ON st.state_key = ts.state_key`                     
`SQL state: 42P01`


What have I done wrong here?

Comment: @Cristoff, I suggest decoding the state name should be the last step. See the edited answer